# xsl:if test "If page is a descendent or self of another page.."

Tags: xml, xslt

I have trying to create a menu where a given tab will be highlighted if the user is on the corresponding page or on the corresponding page's subpages.  I'm new to XSL and need to edit some stuff for work.  Give the following setup:

sample/mock xml

```
   <Page ID="x44">
     <Page ID="x52" />
        <Page ID="x51" />
        <Page ID="x50" />
     </Page>
    <Page ID="x46">
     <Page ID="x22" />
        <Page ID="x21" />
        <Page ID="x20" />
   </Page>
```

and this is the xsl

```
 <li>
    <xsl:attribute name="class" >
             <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[$pageid = 'x44']">
                <xsl:text>active</xsl:text>
             </xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
```

This gets x44 to highlight but none of its children: 52, 51, 50.   Any help or push in the right direction is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide the exact wanted output -- people don't like to guess and waste their time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though question is incomplete as mentioned by hon' Dimitre, also I can't find Element for that attribute **CLASS** !! I assume you want an output something like this:

```
<test class="active" />
```

Then I have prepared  a code:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="test">
  <xsl:attribute name="class" >
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[@ID = 'x44']">
      <xsl:text>active</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Use @ for Attributes, and instead of * you can use element name "**Page**"

The code line `<xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[@ID = 'x44']">` returns true of false based on if **any element having  attribute ID='x44'** ..

***Let us know the required output if you are not satisfied with the answer.***

Answer (score 0):

Your `xsl:if` test will only pass elements who either have the `x44` themselves, or a descendant that does; your `x52` element doesn't match this, the `x44` is a parent/ancestor, not a descendant.

You probably want this:

`<xsl:if test="ancestor-or-self::*[$pageid = 'x44']">`

or possibly

`<xsl:if test="ancestor-or-self::Page[@ID = 'x44']">`